# VBA macro for transposing row and columns based on one condition

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to manage time sheet of my company and have a small issue. I have data ordered in rows per person, however I would like to have them in column format. Currently, data is in following format:
[image: Current organization of working times]

I would like it to have the following shape:

Rules that are to be followed: withing the same name(person) and same date, take the "OUT" time value and put it to the next row. Please note  that there are few thousand rows.

[image: Desired Outcome]

Questions are very welcome
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with Excel formulae instead.

Example: 
- Add a column combining the date and the “IN”/“OUT status
- add a column which looks up the out time for the current row’s date, using the column from the first step as the lookup
- filter so that you keep the “IN”/“OUT” columns but remove the “OUT”/“OUT” ones
- if necessary, automate the above in a macro. Using the macro recorder is probably the easiest way. Then if you like you could manually tidy up the VBA code

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Insert()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1

            If .Range("A" & i).Value = "" And .Range("D" & i).Value = "OUT" Then
                .Range("D" & i - 1).Value = .Range("C" & i).Value
                .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```